# python + how to verify if linux command success in python

Tags: python, linux, bash

How to capture the standard output of command in python script

for example , I want to check if tar command success or not
and results will be return in stndStatus value

```
import commands

def runCommandAndReturnValue():

      status,output = commands.getstatusoutput("  tar xvf Test.tar ")
      return stndStatus
```

other example -  its like $? in shell scripts so stndStatus will be the value of $?

Comment: Take a look at the subprocess module https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense because `stndStatus` is not defined anywhere. Linux commands typically return 0 if successful and an 8-bit signed integer corresponding to an error code otherwise. There is no standard definition of the other error codes, really. Only that zero indicates success.

Comment: i think this modul not support in python 2.X ( this is the version on my linux )

Comment: @Eytan i am using 2.7 and it works very well.

Comment: @Eytan Those are the Python 2 docs and right at the top of the page it says _New in Python 2.4_

Comment: stndStatus is only example , to return the standart output , but I need real example

Answer (score 2):

I need to redirect the output to `DEVNULL`:

```
import subprocess
import os

FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
retcode = subprocess.call(['tar', 'xvf', 'test.tar'],
                          stdout=FNULL,
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print retcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work:

```
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
  retcode = subprocess.call('tar xvd Test.tar', stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

Retcode will have the return value of the command. 0 if success, and something else if not. The output from the command will go to the file, which you can read later.

Comment: is it ok to not write to a file and only to stay with the second line?

Comment: @Eytan what do you mean? You don’t want the output from the command?

Comment: I want the output in the var - retcode but not write to send it to afile

Comment: like this -  retcode = subprocess.call('tar xvd Test.tar')

Comment: @Eytan from the docs: "stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None."

Comment: yes but maybe there are other option without to open file

Comment: ok can you update your answer regarding the last remark , and also include the module in your code for all the users here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87207/discussion-between-eytan-and-rishav-kundu).

Comment: @Eytan no thnx. Make some effort yourself.

Comment: sorry but this isnt work - I mean out/err not writen to the file

Comment: @Eytan that is because `tar` _produces no output_. Try with a command like `ls` and you will see output!